Ruby/Rails Bunny RabbitMQ Must be one of [:method, :headers, :body, :heartbeat]
I get an error when trying to connect to RabbitMQ.
Error backtrace:
.../amq-protocol-2.3.2/lib/amq/protocol/frame.rb:67:in `decode_header'
Error:
Must be one of [:method, :headers, :body, :heartbeat]
conn = Buny.new(***)
con.start
I tried a lot of things until I made an error that turned out to be trivial. I am writing with the hope that this will help others)

Check your connection parameters; if the port is specified as a string, you will receive a similar error.
If you add logs and track type_id, channel, size, then they receive incorrect values ​​because of this. Specify the port as a number and the problem will disappear
